# Displaying ZXING Barcode scanner in Fragment's Layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, zxing

I have an Activity called Scanner with two fragments each using 1/2 of the display. What I am trying to achieve is running a ZXING barcode scanner in the one fragment and display the scan results in the other fragment.

I am using callback to the activity to communicate between the two fragments. Have tested that part with a button in one and a text view in the other.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a way (yet) to run the scanner only in the one fragment. As soon as I initiate the scanner it uses the full display for the view finder.

The scanners' first parameter is Activity and I suspect that might be where I am doing something wrong?

My Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0@aar'
```

The code to launch the scanner:

```
    public void startScanner(Activity a,int cam){

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(a);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
    integrator.setCameraId(cam);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of using ZXING simply calls their app to do the scanning, it's not part of your code.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions to how I can achieve running a barcode scanner in a set layout? What you are mentioning I am already aware of

Comment: What I guess you need to do is download their code and modify it to your tastes from https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android